# random.choice has an issue counting its arguments

Tags: python, random

I have an issue with `random.choice` in the random module. So here I have a nice looking block of code:

```
for trap in range(11):
    leftorright = raw_input("")
    if leftorright == "left" or "right":
        leftchoice = random.choice(True, False)
        if leftchoice:
            print "You don't feel anything on your legs, so you think you're okay."
        else:
            print "You feel a sharp pain on your %s leg." %(random.choice("left", "right"))
    else:
        print sorrycommand
```

So the issue here is that the two `random.choice` instances (`leftchoice = random.choice(True, False)` and `print "You feel a sharp pain on your %s leg." %(random.choice("left", "right"))`) are giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 408, in <module>
    startmenuchoice() 
  File "main.py", line 404, in startmenuchoice
    room7()
  File "main.py", line 386, in room7
    leftchoice = random.choice(True, False)
TypeError: choice() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Now, going right to the real thing here: `TypeError: choice() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

It says in the error that there are **3** arguments given, but if you take a look at the error *and* the code, there are clearly only **2** arguments given (the proper amount of arguments needed). Could somebody please help me?

Side notes:

1. I will provide any other info needed in the comments since I am not very good of thinking of every bit of needed info.
2. I am using the site repl.it, an online IDE and compiler. Maybe that might have something to do with it?

Comment: The third argument is `self`. Yes, this is confusing.

Comment: Even worse, `random.choice` is actually the `choice` method of a module-level instance of `random.Random`, rather than a separate function (`choice = _inst.choice`). As a result, the error message doesn't make much sense if you think `choice` is a regular function.

Comment: In Python, the syntax `thing.function(args...)` is roughly equivalent to `method(thing, args...)` where `method` is the specified method in the class of `thing`.

Comment: Also, line 3, `or` doesn't work like that. You need a boolean expression on both sides. I suggest you use `in` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`random.choice` doesn't take multiple arguments; it takes a single *sequence* from which to choose a value.

```
leftchoice = random.choice([True, False])
```

---

The `random` module defines a class, `Random`, that encapsulates a random number generator. You make an instance, with an optional seed to initialize it, then call its methods to get various random values.

```
gen = random.Random(2382948)
x = gen.choice([True, False])
```

This is great for testing, as you can create *reproducible* random sequences by using the same seed. However, in general use, you may not care about the seed and be happy with some default seed (here, a value based on a value returned by `os.urandom`). To facilitate that use case, the `random` module creates a module-level instance of `Random` when it is imported:

```
_inst = Random()
```

and creates a bunch of module-level aliases to that instance's methods:

```
...
choice = _inst.choice
```

So `random.choice`, rather than being a function that takes one sequence argument, is *really* a bound method whose underlying unbound method takes two arguments (an instance and a sequence), and thus just needs one more. (Remember that `_inst.choice([True, False])` resolves to Random.choice(_inst, [True, False])`.)

The error message you see is for `random.choice(True, False)` is due to the fact that you are effectively trying to call `Random.choice`, defined as

```
def choice(self, seq):
    ...
```

as `_inst.choice(True, False)` or (`Random.choice(_inst, True, False)`), and it should be clear now that you have one argument too many.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh. oohh. ok i get it. I took the square brackets out coz i found it somewhere on stack overflow and assumed the square brackets were there coz it was an example. welp, i get it now. thanks!